# What brand of RAM will be closely match with SK Hynix HMT351S6EFR8A-PB DDR3-1600 PC3L-12800 SO-DIMM RAM?

Tags: memory, dell-inspiron, ddr3

I am looking to add an extra 4 GB RAM to my Dell Inspiron 15 i3 laptop. I am not able to find the exact RAM in India. Which one should I prefer then, Crucial or Transcend or Corsair? These seems to be common on Indian e-commerce platforms. Most of these brands have similar offering.

Here is CPUID report for current RAM module.

```
DIMM #              1
SMBus address       0x52
Memory type     DDR3
Module format       SO-DIMM
Manufacturer (ID)   Hyundai Electronics (AD000000000000000000)
Size            4096 MBytes
Max bandwidth       PC3-12800 (800 MHz)
Part number     HMT351S6EFR8A-PB  
Serial number       125356BA
Manufacturing date  Week 06/Year 13
Number of banks     8
Nominal Voltage     1.35 Volts
EPP         no
XMP         no
AMP         no
JEDEC timings table     CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC @ frequency
JEDEC #1        5.0-5-5-14-19 @ 380 MHz
JEDEC #2        6.0-6-6-16-22 @ 457 MHz
JEDEC #3        7.0-7-7-19-26 @ 533 MHz
JEDEC #4        8.0-8-8-22-30 @ 609 MHz
JEDEC #5        9.0-9-9-24-33 @ 685 MHz
JEDEC #6        10.0-10-10-27-37 @ 761 MHz
JEDEC #7        11.0-11-11-28-39 @ 800 MHz
```

Comment: Unfortunately, hardware recommendation questions are off-topic as they [tend to become obsolete quickly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and often aren't useful to other readers. Instead of asking for a specific product, you should ask about *how* to find a particular device that meets your needs.

Comment: I understand your emotions, but I would have preferred answer like what I blogged at https://takneekivichar.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/things-to-remember-when-buying-ram-for-laptop-in-india/ after purchase. Thanks anyway, I have figured out what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to just buy an 8GB Dual channel kit.
If that's not an option then I would suggest using a DDR3 PC3-12800 using the 800Mhz timings as your point of reference when searching for additional memory, since that is the actual speed of the memory. 
I would think that most any memory module of PC3-12800 would work.

Comment: Concur with Michael. I know it will be more expensive, but I would avoid mixing models of different brands, even if the specs are compatible.

Comment: I bought a corsair 4 GB exactly matching my current one. http://www.corsair.com/en/corsair-memory-4gb-ddr3l-sodimm-memory-cmso4gx3m1c1600c11 
Its working fine as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Any memory module that conforms to the specs below will work:

```
Memory type         DDR3 PC3L-12800 (800 MHz)
Module format       SO-DIMM
Size                4096 MBytes (4 GB)
Voltage             1.35 Volts
Timings             11-11-11-28-39 @ 800 MHz
```

I would recommend you to pick whichever ones you can find at the lowest price.

Otherwise, use the [Crucial Memory Advisor](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en) to find specific model number. You will need a four digit code, "Dell Inspiron 15" wasn't enough for me to find your exact model (you should be able to find this product code on a label under your laptop).

Example product: [4GB DDR3 PC3-12800 Unbuffered NON-ECC 1.35V - 
CT51264BF160B](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/memory/ct51264bf160b)

Comment: Crucial is not officially supported in India so I went with http://www.corsair.com/en/corsair-memory-4gb-ddr3l-sodimm-memory-cmso4gx3m1c1600c11 . Crucial Advisor did help me. I cannot upvote since I need 15 reputations ;-) Thanks anyway.